# How to make the second event start after the first one

Tags: vb.net

How to make the second event start after the first one.
Below is a code that copies files from 2 different paths set by the user for me. On the other hand, it wants to make the first copy from another path before it goes to the next one.

```
Public Sub StartCopy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartCopy.Click

    ' Reset variables
    _stopped = False
    ' Create the FileCopy class which will initiate the threads
    CopyFiles = New FileCopy
    CopyFiles.FromPath = My.Settings.pathmemfrom1
    CopyFiles.ToPath = My.Settings.pathmemto1

    ' Initiate the copy, count  from the FileCopy class
    CopyFiles.StartCopy()
    WorkingBar.Minimum = 0
    WorkingBar.Maximum = 100
    WorkingLabel.Visible = True
    WorkingBar.Visible = True

    ' Reset form controls
    setting.Panel.Enabled = False
    StopCopy.Enabled = True
    ViewLog.Enabled = True

    CopyFiles.Dispose()


    'Reset veriables
    _stopped = False


    ' Create the FileCopy class which will initiate the threads

    CopyFiles2 = New FileCopy
    CopyFiles2.FromPath = My.Settings.pathmemfrom2
    CopyFiles2.ToPath = My.Settings.pathmemto2

    CopyFiles2.StartCopy()
    WorkingBar.Minimum = 0
    WorkingBar.Maximum = 100
    WorkingLabel.Visible = True
    WorkingBar.Visible = True

    ' Reset form controls

    setting.Panel.Enabled = False
    StopCopy.Enabled = True
    ViewLog.Enabled = True

    CopyFiles2.Dispose()

    'Reset veriables
    _stopped = False
```

Comment: You're making very little sense. Do you mean that you want those two `FileCopy` objects to do their work simultaneously? It's pretty much impossible for us to provide any sort of detail, given that we have no idea how that class works. Suffice it to say that you need to have each one work on its own thread. Other than that, your question is far too vague.

Comment: I would like to do so so that copyfile2 starts up when the copyfile ends.

Comment: Ah, so they are presumably already doing their work asynchronously.  In that case you need to be able to detect when the first operation ends.  Read about that class and see what it offers, e.g. and even you can handle.  You can then initiate the second operation from that event handler.  Maybe the class offers a synchronous alternative, e.g. a `Copy` method instead of `StartCopy`.

Comment: By the way, you should not be disposing those objects if they are still performing work.  Don't dispose an object until you're finished using it.